# Sequencing along 2 hierachies in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a sequence of numbers based on month, but want the sequence to reset once the "period" has changed.

sample data

```
period <- c("1", "1", "1", "1","0", "0", "0","0")
month <- c("Jan2019", "Jan2019", "Jan2019", "Feb2019", "Feb2020", "Mar2020", "Mar2020","Apr2020")
```

My desired output would be

```
  period month     results
 "1"    "Jan2019" "1"    
 "1"    "Jan2019" "1"    
 "1"    "Jan2019" "1"    
 "1"    "Feb2019" "2"    
 "0"    "Feb2020" "1"    
 "0"    "Mar2020" "2"    
 "0"    "Mar2020" "2"    
 "0"    "Apr2020" "3"
```

I have used the cur_group_ID with FUN=seq to get the sequence, but am struggling with the "restart numbering with new period" bit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working!

```
df=df %>%
     group_by(period) %>%
     mutate(series = match(month, unique(month)))
```